# Do rust crate features need do get installed separately?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a hard time understanding the features entry in the Rust toml.

Let's say I have a dependency (in this case sqlx) saying

```
sqlx = { version = "0.4.0-beta.1", default-features = false, features = [ "runtime-tokio", "macros", "json", "mysql" ] }
```

The Rust book says regarding [***Features***](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html):

> Cargo supports features to allow expression of:
>
> - conditional compilation options (usable through cfg attributes);
> - optional dependencies, which enhance a package, but are not required; and
> - clusters of optional dependencies, such as postgres-all, that would include the postgres package, the postgres-macros package, and
>   possibly other packages (such as development-time mocking libraries,
>   debugging tools, etc.).
>
> A feature of a package is either an optional dependency, or a set of
> other features.

What does that mean in my case? Do I have to install, i.e. enter e.g. "runtime-tokio" as an additional dependency in my Cargo.toml or does sqlx already come with "runtime-tokio"?

BTW what are cfg-attributes?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute

Comment: Enabling a feature tells cargo to pull in all dependencies needed for the feature. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you specify features for a dependency, you're asking Cargo to *compile that dependency differently,* in a way that the crate has chosen to provide as an option. Often, but not always, the feature is named the same as a crate that it could depend on (to provide e.g. trait implementations).

> Do I have to install, i.e. enter e.g. "runtime-tokio" as an additional dependency in my Cargo.toml or does sqlx already come with "runtime-tokio"?

No; the Cargo.toml for `sqlx` will take care of specifying needed dependencies for any combination of features.

> what are cfg-attributes?

Attributes are the things written `#[attribute_name_here]`, like `#[test]` and `#[derive(Debug)]`. [The `#[cfg(...)]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) allows conditional compilation, i.e. telling the compiler to pretend certain parts of the source code don't exist.

Often, a feature has two effects:

- It enables an optional dependency (this is specified in `Cargo.toml`, either explicitly in [the `[features]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) or implicitly by the feature having the same name as a crate dependency).
- It causes the code in the crate that uses that dependency to be compiled (rather than ignored), using conditional compilation.